# CakePHP- Imap_Source Plugin - Missing Datasource

Tags: php, email, cakephp, imap

I am currently struggling,  trying to integrate an [Email Imap](https://github.com/nicolasramy/cakephp-emails-plugin) plugin, which I need for the application I am building, but somehow I cannot get cake to load the datasource inside the file.

My file structure is currently as follows

```
Plugin\emails\models\datasources\imap_source.php
```

My database Config :

```
public $emailTicket = array(
        'datasource' => 'emails.imap',
        'server' => 'imap.gmail.com',
        'connect' => 'imap/tls/novalidate-cert',
        'username' => 'myemail@domain.com',
        'password' => '**********',
        'port' => '143', //incoming port 
        'ssl' => true,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'error_handler' => 'php',
        'auto_mark_as' => array(
        'Seen',
        // 'Answered',
        // 'Flagged',
        // 'Deleted',
        // 'Draft',
        ),
    );
```

What other values I tried for the datasource key :

> - 'Emails.ImapSource' (I read that datasource should be camelcase) but this gives Missing plugin error since the plugin folder name start with lower case.
> - 'emails.models.datasources.imap_source'
> - 'emails.imap_source'
> - 'emails.imapSource'
> - 'emails.ImapSource'

Also In case you were wandering, yes I am loading plugin from bootstrap
tried `CakePlugin::load('emails');` and `CakePlugin::load('Emails');`

I am sure this is some naming convention which im missing. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

PLEASE HELP, I'M DESPERATE here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you downloaded the correct version of that plugin.

You should download this one:

https://github.com/nicolasramy/cakephp-emails-plugin/tree/cake-2.0

And with that, you can place it directly into your `app/Model/Datasource/ImapSource.php`. You don't need to create a plugin for it.

It should work if you do it this way, unless you are using CakePHP 1.3, which I dont think you are since you said you are building an application.

Thanks,

Comment: AKKA-Web Thank you for answering! im going to try it NOW! if this works I wll mar it as answered, and also forever indebted to you!!

Comment: Can't believe this worked!!! After 4hours of excruciating headache trying to figure out why the Datasource could not be found!!

Comment: You are welcome @user2678538... it happens. You just have to learn from it.